# If a user uploads a 2000x2000 px image and then I display it as 400x400 px, does the page use bandwidth as if the image is 2000x2000px?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website where people can upload images which are then shown on the index page, however, I've been wondering whether displaying 2000x2000px image in  tag whose width and height is set to 400x400px slows down the loading time of the page/images.

Comment: yes, it does...the image  will be rendered by the browser

Comment: You can test this by right clicking and viewing image. You'll see the source image!

Comment: So I assume I have to use some PHP library to create several copies of the same image in different resolutions which I intend to use whenever an image us uploaded?

Comment: @Bobimaru Yes, you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the image will still need to be transmitted over the network in it's entirety before the client (browser) can scale it down.

Unless there is some server-side scaling done, the webserver doesn't know (and has no way to know) what size the user is expecting so it will simply serve up the file as uploaded and the client (browser) will scale it to the desired size. You can check this, [as @l3fty points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525976/if-a-user-uploads-a-2000x2000-px-image-and-then-i-display-it-as-400x400-px-does/50526002#comment88063762_50525976), by right-clicking the image and viewing it or by entering the images' url directly into the addressbar.

Some CMS'es or other applications might scale your image server-side when uploaded or on demand but this depends on the application, it's configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

yes it will page use bandwidth as if the image is 2000x2000px. Because the source of your image will be with the default size and dimensions